# Type or namespace "Player" could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I write this program and I get Type or namespace "Player" could not be found can anyone help me?
Also  [SerializeField] do not show me the field Player on the Inspector to select the obect I want.

I really do not understand why this happen.

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LeveGenerator : MonoBehaviour{

private const float PLAYER_DISTANCE_SPAWN_LEVEL_PART = 200f;

[SerializeField] private Transform levelPart_Start;
[SerializeField] private Transform levelPart_1;
[SerializeField] private Player player;


private Vector3 lastEndPosition;

private void Awake(){
lastEndPosition = levelPart_Start.Find("EndPosition").position;
    int startingSpawnLevelParts = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < startingSpawnLevelParts; i++) {
        SpawnLevelPart();
    }
}

private void Update() {
    if (Vector3.Distance(player.GetPosition(), lastEndPosition) < PLAYER_DISTANCE_SPAWN_LEVEL_PART) {
        // Spawn another level part
        SpawnLevelPart();
    }
}

private void SpawnLevelPart(){
    Transform lastLevelPartTransform = SpawnLevelPart(lastEndPosition);
    lastEndPosition = lastLevelPartTransform.Find("EndPosition").position;
}


private Transform SpawnLevelPart(Vector3 spawnPosition)
{
Transform levelPartTransform = Instantiate(levelPart_1, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
return levelPartTransform;
}

}
```

Comment: Is Player a class in your Unity project and if yes could you add it as well.

Comment: What namespace is `Player` contained in?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there could be few mistakes.

First of all - the script you posted has a mistypo in the name (**LeveGenerator**, instead of, I assume, **LevelGenerator**). Make sure that the file name is correct aswell.

Secondly - it might not even be a problem with this particular script. You should have posted the Player script too.

Make sure that the Player script doesn't have a *namespace{}* in it and check if the name of the class matches its file name, because it is a common mistake. Just because your file is named *Player.cs*, doesn't mean that the class is named *Player*.